# Poetry+mypy ignoring importing modules while poetry+python works fine

Tags: python, mypy, python-poetry

I've definitely botched my python package setup in a way that is failing to properly import packages with mypy despite running fine with python itself, but I can't quite tell how or what the solution is.  I've been able to repro the problem with a pretty minimal approach.

**The Setup**

```
poetry new foo
cd foo
poetry add mypy@latest
poetry install
poetry shell
```

then create the following file structure:

```
pyproject.toml
poetry.lock
    foo/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        bar/
            __init__.py
            b.py
```

```python
# a.py
from foo.bar import b
will_fail: int = "a.py string"
print(will_fail)

# b.py
will_fail: int = "b.py string"
print(will_fail)
```

As expected running `python foo/a.py` executes both a.py and b.py and prints both statements.
And running `mypy foo` gives the expected errors:

```
foo/bar/b.py:1: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
foo/a.py:3: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
Found 2 errors in 2 files (checked 4 source files)
```

**The Problem**

But running `mypy foo/a.py` *only* gives:

```
foo/a.py:3: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

And running `mypy foo/a.py --follow-imports=error` gives:

```
foo/a.py: error: Ancestor package "foo" ignored
foo/a.py: note: (Using --follow-imports=error, submodule passed on command line)
foo/a.py:1: error: Import of "foo.bar.b" ignored
foo/a.py:1: note: (Using --follow-imports=error, module not passed on command line)
foo/a.py:1: error: Import of "foo.bar" ignored
foo/a.py:3: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

**The Question**

So why is mypy *not* following into the modules and type checking them as they are imported?

Am I making some critical mistake in how I'm using poetry?  mypy?  python?

I've read the mypy docs a million times (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#how-mypy-handles-imports) and it seems like what's happening is some "fourth" option from the 3 described there?

Comment: Try
`from ..bar import b`

for a relative import

or you need to indicate how a is supposed to find b (as specifiying only foo/a.py does not allow the module structure to be loaded by mypy it seems ?)

Edit: you can see mypy ignore the foo ancestor package in the error message `foo/a.py: error: Ancestor package "foo" ignored
foo/a.py: note: (Using --follow-imports=error, submodule passed on command line)
foo/a.py:1: error: Import of "foo.bar.b" ignored
foo/a.py:1: note: (Using --follow-imports=error, module not passed on command line)
foo/a.py:1: error: Import of "foo.bar" ignored`

Comment: Thanks @IceTDrinker!  I guess my question is *why* is mypy ignoring the ancestor package?  mypy knows it's there, but it's ignoring it?  that seems wrong.  is there some way I can tell it to start paying attention to the ancestor package?

Comment: I really don't know :/ I saw this link: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#finding-imports where you may have luck with the MYPYPATH but when I tried it, it did not seem to work. Is there a reason to check mypy in this way (a specifci file)? `mypy -p foo` would allow to check all the source code in foo and load all relevant modules/files

Comment: Fair question.  I'm in that awkward "add type annotations to an existing code base" phase and was trying to do the rollout incrementally over files but with the goal of being certain each file and its imports were OK.  I'm thinking that's just probably making life harder for myself though and I might pursue the 'package by package' route you're suggesting.

Comment: I think you can ignore typing for whole packages, so start typing somewhere and ignore everything else? As type hints are a bit "contaminating" it's probably how I would go about it.